# don't start Android application in React native

Tags: android, react-native

Finally i could resolve by making new project.
and copy code and add library one by one.
i could clean my project.
it means i could throw unneeded libraries and something.

thank you!

i'm trying to use react-native-webview for my application.
In iOS,it works well.
In Android ,it doesn't.
And unfortunatelly,i don know the reason.
i reserched a lot.
unfortunatelly,i still have a problem.
it produced this error on Android studio.
because it doesn't produces any error by running this command.

```
react-native run-android
```

so i can't understand why it doesn't work.
so i tried to build it on android studio,then it produced this error.

```
2020-04-29 00:34:25.444 19491-19530/com.hiratsuka_react_native_test E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
2020-04-29 00:34:25.446 19491-19530/com.hiratsuka_react_native_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: com.hiratsuka_react_native_test, PID: 19491
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:789)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:639)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:27)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:952)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

my env is here.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5

      {
    "name": "hiratsuka_react_native_test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "android": "react-native run-android",
      "ios": "react-native run-ios",
      "start": "react-native start",
      "test": "jest",
      "lint": "eslint .",
      "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
      "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
      "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.0",
      "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
      "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
      "@unimodules/core": "^5.0.0",
      "axios": "^0.19.2",
      "expo-asset": "^8.0.0",
      "expo-constants": "^8.0.0",
      "expo-font": "^8.0.0",
      "jest-worker": "^25.2.6",
      "react": "16.9.0",
      "react-native": "0.61.5",
      "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
      "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
      "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
      "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
      "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
      "react-native-unimodules": "^0.8.1",
      "react-native-webview": "^9.3.0",
      "react-navigation": "^4.3.4",
      "realm": "5.0.0",
      "typescript": "^3.7.0-beta"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "7.8.7",
      "@babel/runtime": "7.8.7",
      "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
      "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.17",
      "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.17",
      "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.17",
      "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.17",
      "@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.17",
      "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
      "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
      "eslint": "^5.0.0",
      "jest": "24.9.0",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
      "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
      "react-native-storybook-loader": "^1.8.1",
      "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

i tried to clean cache,change gradle,or something.but it didn't work.

before using react-native-webview,it worked well.
please help.

app/build.gradle is here.

```
      apply plugin: "com.android.application"

  import com.android.build.OutputFile

  /**
   * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
   * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
   * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
   * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
   * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
   * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
   * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
   *
   * project.ext.react = [
   *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
   *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
   *
   *   // the entry file for bundle generation
   *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
   *
   *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
   *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
   *   bundleInDebug: false,
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
   *   bundleInRelease: true,
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
   *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
   *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
   *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
   *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
   *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
   *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
   *   // bundleInBeta: true,
   *
   *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
   *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
   *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
   *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
   *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
   *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
   *
   *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
   *   root: "../../",
   *
   *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
   *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
   *
   *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
   *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
   *
   *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
   *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
   *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
   *
   *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
   *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
   *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
   *
   *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
   *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
   *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
   *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
   *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
   *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
   *
   *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
   *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
   *
   *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
   *   extraPackagerArgs: []
   * ]
   */

  project.ext.react = [
      entryFile: "index.js",
      root: "../../",
      enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
  ]

  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

  apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'


  /**
   * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
   *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
   *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
   * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
   * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
   * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
   */
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

  /**
   * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
   */
  def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
  def useIntlJsc = false

  /**
   * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
   *
   * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
   * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
   *
   * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
   * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
   * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
   * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
   */
  def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

  /**
   * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
   *
   * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
   * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
   * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
   */
  def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

  android {
      compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      }

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.hiratsuka_react_native_test"
          minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
          targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
      }
      splits {
          abi {
              reset()
              enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
              universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
              include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
          }
      }
      signingConfigs {
          debug {
              storeFile file('debug.keystore')
              storePassword 'android'
              keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
              keyPassword 'android'
          }
      }
      buildTypes {
          debug {
              signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
          }
          release {
              // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
              // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
              signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
              minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
          }
      }
      // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
          variant.outputs.each { output ->
              // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
              // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
              def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
              def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
              if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                  output.versionCodeOverride =
                          versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
              }

          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      implementation project(':react-native-webview')
      implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      addUnimodulesDependencies()
      api project(':unimodules-core')

      if (enableHermes) {
          def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
          debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
          releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
      } else {
          implementation jscFlavor
      }


      // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

      // For animated GIF support
      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

      // For WebP support, including animated WebP
      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.1.0'
      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'

      // For WebP support, without animations
      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
  }

  // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
  // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
  task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
      from configurations.compile
      into 'libs'
  }


  apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile   : "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // HERE!
]
```

Comment: updated my answer, give it a try and see if it fixes it

Comment: ahhh,still have an error.i added my build.gradle.could you check it?